# Lots of videos won't show on android smartphone

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

I have a website with around 30 videos in a card design. While working great on Desktop, the videos won't load properly on my android smartphone. I use .mov because its working good with iOS + Windows and use data-src to load in while in viewport later. I tested it with .mp4 files and had the same issue. The src element is an element to fill the card until its changed.

How I reproduce the issue:
-Create html file with code below and put it on my local webserver XAMPP
-Browse local IP from my smartphone

Issue:
Some videos will load but most not. When refreshing page it's possible that other videos that didn't work work and videos that worked not work.

I had to remove the filename for privacy reasons.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>

<video class="vid" playsinline muted loop src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAMAAAACCAQAAAA3fa6RAAAADklEQVR42mNkAANGCAUAACMAA2w/AMgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" data-src="./assets/videos/" alt="" type="video/quicktime"></video>
<video class="vid" playsinline muted loop src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAMAAAACCAQAAAA3fa6RAAAADklEQVR42mNkAANGCAUAACMAA2w/AMgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" data-src="./assets/videos/" alt="" type="video/quicktime"></video>
<video class="vid" playsinline muted loop src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAMAAAACCAQAAAA3fa6RAAAADklEQVR42mNkAANGCAUAACMAA2w/AMgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" data-src="./assets/videos/" alt="" type="video/quicktime"></video>
<video type="video/quicktime" class="vid" playsinline muted loop src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAMAAAACCAQAAAA3fa6RAAAADklEQVR42mNkAANGCAUAACMAA2w/AMgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" data-src="./assets/videos/" alt=""></video>
<video type="video/quicktime" class="vid" playsinline muted loop src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAMAAAACCAQAAAA3fa6RAAAADklEQVR42mNkAANGCAUAACMAA2w/AMgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" data-src="./assets/videos/" alt=""></video>
<video type="video/quicktime" class="vid" playsinline muted loop src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAMAAAACCAQAAAA3fa6RAAAADklEQVR42mNkAANGCAUAACMAA2w/AMgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" data-src="./assets/videos/" alt=""></video>
<video type="video/quicktime" class="vid" playsinline muted loop src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAMAAAACCAQAAAA3fa6RAAAADklEQVR42mNkAANGCAUAACMAA2w/AMgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" data-src="./assets/videos/" alt=""></video>
<video type="video/quicktime" class="vid" playsinline muted loop src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAMAAAACCAQAAAA3fa6RAAAADklEQVR42mNkAANGCAUAACMAA2w/AMgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" data-src="./assets/videos/" alt=""></video>
<video type="video/quicktime" class="vid" playsinline muted  loop src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAMAAAACCAQAAAA3fa6RAAAADklEQVR42mNkAANGCAUAACMAA2w/AMgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" data-src="./assets/videos/" alt=""></video>
<video type="video/quicktime" class="vid" playsinline muted loop src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAMAAAACCAQAAAA3fa6RAAAADklEQVR42mNkAANGCAUAACMAA2w/AMgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" data-src="./assets/videos/" alt=""></video>
<video type="video/quicktime" class="vid" playsinline muted loop src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAMAAAACCAQAAAA3fa6RAAAADklEQVR42mNkAANGCAUAACMAA2w/AMgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" data-src="./assets/videos/" alt=""></video>
<video type="video/quicktime" class="vid" playsinline muted loop src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAMAAAACCAQAAAA3fa6RAAAADklEQVR42mNkAANGCAUAACMAA2w/AMgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" data-src="./assets/videos/" alt=""></video>
<video type="video/quicktime" class="vid" playsinline muted loop src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAMAAAACCAQAAAA3fa6RAAAADklEQVR42mNkAANGCAUAACMAA2w/AMgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" data-src="./assets/videos/" alt=""></video>
<video type="video/quicktime" class="vid" playsinline muted loop src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAMAAAACCAQAAAA3fa6RAAAADklEQVR42mNkAANGCAUAACMAA2w/AMgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" data-src="./assets/videos/" alt=""></video>
<video type="video/quicktime" class="vid" playsinline muted loop src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAMAAAACCAQAAAA3fa6RAAAADklEQVR42mNkAANGCAUAACMAA2w/AMgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" data-src="./assets/videos/" alt=""></video>
<video type="video/quicktime" class="vid" playsinline muted loop src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAMAAAACCAQAAAA3fa6RAAAADklEQVR42mNkAANGCAUAACMAA2w/AMgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" data-src="./assets/videos/" alt=""></video>
<video type="video/quicktime" class="vid" playsinline muted loop src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAMAAAACCAQAAAA3fa6RAAAADklEQVR42mNkAANGCAUAACMAA2w/AMgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" data-src="./assets/videos/" alt=""></video>

<script type="text/javascript">
// load images when in viewport
refresh_handler = function(e) {
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("*[data-src]");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var boundingClientRect = elements[i].getBoundingClientRect();
        if (elements[i].hasAttribute("data-src")) {
            elements[i].setAttribute("src", elements[i].getAttribute("data-src"));
            elements[i].removeAttribute("data-src");
        }
    }
};
window.addEventListener('scroll', refresh_handler);
window.addEventListener('load', refresh_handler);
window.addEventListener('resize', refresh_handler);
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: .mov isn't a good choice [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/Containers] but for your specific issue you're probably hitting a concurrency limit in how many requests a browser can make to the same origin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have wasted hours of research to locate the problem without result, however I have at least found a workaround. When giving the `video` a `poster` attribute of the videos first frame as `png`, then everything shows correct on all possible devices. I will mark it as solved, but the root of the problem isnt found. When working without the `poster` attribute some videos wont load and if you go on `download video`, the video got an error and cannot be displayed by android video app. Very strange..., maybe i have hit the cache limit or something, would need more time to investigate, which i dont have.